# Assigning pandas columns based on set of reference list

Tags: python, pandas, assign

The objective is to assign the column `main_frame` value to a list of reference.

Currently, the operation is achieved as below:

```
import pandas as pd

watchlist_ref = [['A1','AA2','A3'],
                ['B1','BC2','B3']]
upper_ref = ['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame ({'tw':['A1','AA2','A3','B1','BC2','B3']})

for ls_str, ws in zip(watchlist_ref, upper_ref):
    df.loc[(df['tw'].str.contains('|'.join(ls_str), case=False)), 'main_frame'] = ws
```

Which give the output below:

```
    tw main_frame
0   A1          A
1  AA2          A
2   A3          A
3   B1          B
4  BC2          B
5   B3          B
```

But, is there any way to avoid the use of `for-loop`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary containing the watchlist values as keys and the reference as value and then use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True` to create the new column:

```py
d = {'|'.join(ls_str): ws for ls_str, ws in zip(watchlist_ref, upper_ref)}
df['main_frame'] = df['tw'].replace(d, regex=True)
```

Result:

```
     tw  main_frame
0    A1           A
1   AA2           A
2    A3           A
3    B1           B
4   BC2           B
5    B3           B
```

Comment: I like this approach as it is robust to potential mis arrangement between the `watchlist_ref` and  `upper_ref`. For example, instead of ` ['A','B']`, one can potentially wrongly arrange it as `['B' ,'A']` which is wrong in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `explode` then `map`

```
s = pd.Series(watchlist_ref,index=upper_ref).explode()
df['new'] = df.tw.map(dict(zip(s,s.index)))
df
Out[175]: 
    tw new
0   A1   A
1  AA2   A
2   A3   A
3   B1   B
4  BC2   B
5   B3   B
```